# Task List how can I Stop task C#

Tags: c#, list, task

How can I stop tasks in the list to realize once again.

```
for (f = 0; f < 3; f++)
{
    list1.ForEach(t => t.Start());
    list1.ForEach(t => t.Wait());

    Task.WaitAll(list1.ToArray());

    //here is problem
    list1.ForEach(t => t.Cancel());
}
```

Comment: Please explain a bit more. I cannot understand your question.

Comment: I need to realize this loop, but after one execution I get Error "Error 1 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' does not contain a definition for 'IsCancellationRequested' and no extension method 'IsCancellationRequested' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Answer (score 1):

The task cannot cancel itself. From the code you showed looks like you have a list of tasks. If you then want to be able to cancel the task while your code is executed you have to create a `CancellationTokenSource` and pass a `CancellationToken` to the task's constructor:

```
list1.Add(new Task<string>((x) => { return x.ToString(); }, cancelationTokenSource.Token));
```

(In the code above I assumed the task is expected to return a string but it will work for any task.)

Then if you need to cancel the task you use the `cancelationTokenSource`:

```
cancelationTokenSource.Cancel();
```

This will terminate the task. What you then can do on the task itself is to check if it has been cancelled:

```
list1.ForEach(t =>
{
    if (t.IsCanceled)
    {

    }
}
```

Hope that helps. My answer is based on my interpretation of your code as there was not too much explained in the question. If you need more specifics please clarify.

Comment: Can I add task like here ?

       ` List<Task> list1 = new List<Task>();

                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)

                {

                    list1.Add(new Task(actionA));

                }`

Comment: Actually, `cancelationTokenSource.Cancel` won't cancel the task in a `Thread.Abort` way - instead it will tell the task to stop when _and if_ the task asks its `CancellationToken` whether it should stop the next time. Additionally, the task has to know its `CancellationToken`, passing it into `Task.Run` just makes its status become `Canceled` instead of `Failed` if the token throws a `TaskCanceledException`...

Comment: There's no need for cancellation in this scenario since all tasks have been completed due to the call to WaitAll();

Answer (score 0):

Couple of thing first:

**Do not** use the task constructor. **Do use** Task.Run() see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/06/13/10024153.aspx

But in your case I am not even sure you should be using Tasks at all. For loops there is PLINQ.

this piece of code inside a loop

```
list1.ForEach(t => t.Start());
list1.ForEach(t => t.Wait());
```

basically makes it run start a task, and then wait for it before starting the next loop.

I suggest using Parallel.ForAll() when you need several CPU bound operations to complete in the loop. If it is IO bound use async /await

Then, what you try to do is to cancel the tasks after you have waited for them to complete. That makes no sense, or I don't understand well enough what you want to accomplish.

Now, lets talk about cancelling the work. You need something like this:

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
var ct = cts.Token;
```

provide the CancellationToken ct to the the tasks in list1. Then call cts.Cancel() to cancel al the tasks that are given the token. 
For example `Task.Run(asyncWork, ct)` where asyncWork is the action you want to perform.

In the action asyncWork, check for cancellation using `ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();`

See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/andrewarnottms/2014/03/19/recommended-patterns-for-cancellationtoken/

You need to provide more about the tasks you put in list1 for better advice.